# Extracting nested items in JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ibm-watson

I'm using `IBM Watson` and `python3` to translate an audio file into a text file. It returns the results in a JSON-format. The resulting JSON is like this...

```
{
"results": [
{
  "alternatives": [
    {
      "transcript": "Marcus white is the managing director of quartz power group an energy company ",
      "confidence": 0.85,
      "word_confidence": [
        [
          "Marcus",
          0.678
        ],
        [
          "white",
          0.99
        ],
        [
          "is",
          0.988
        ],
        [
          "the",
          1.0
        ],
        [
          "managing",
          1.0
        ],
        [
          "director",
          1.0
        ],
        [
          "of",
          1.0
        ],
        [
          "quartz",
          0.394
        ],
        [
          "power",
          0.737
        ],
        [
          "group",
          0.968
        ],
        [
          "an",
          0.783
        ],
        [
          "energy",
          0.989
        ],
        [
          "company",
          0.844
        ]
      ],
      "timestamps": [
        [
          "Marcus",
          12.28,
          12.78
        ],
        [
          "white",
          12.78,
          13.17
        ],
        [
          "is",
          13.17,
          13.33
        ],
        [
          "the",
          13.33,
          13.42
        ],
        [
          "managing",
          13.42,
          13.83
        ],
        [
          "director",
          13.83,
          14.39
        ],
        [
          "of",
          14.39,
          14.52
        ],
        [
          "quartz",
          14.52,
          15.0
        ],
        [
          "power",
          15.0,
          15.36
        ],
        [
          "group",
          15.36,
          15.79
        ],
        [
          "an",
          15.93,
          16.08
        ],
        [
          "energy",
          16.08,
          16.45
        ],
        [
          "company",
          16.45,
          16.95
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "final": true
},
{
  "alternatives": [
    {
      "transcript": "every month the departmental manages meet to discuss high level issues in the company ",
      "confidence": 0.925,
      "word_confidence": [
        [
          "every",
          1.0
        ],
        [
          "month",
          0.993
        ],
        [
          "the",
          0.728
        ],
        [
          "departmental",
          1.0
        ],
        [
          "manages",
          0.7
        ],
        [
          "meet",
          0.77
        ],
        [
          "to",
          1.0
        ],
        [
          "discuss",
          1.0
        ],
        [
          "high",
          0.835
        ],
        [
          "level",
          0.984
        ],
        [
          "issues",
          1.0
        ],
        [
          "in",
          0.67
        ],
        [
          "the",
          0.927
        ],
        [
          "company",
          0.994
        ]
      ],
      "timestamps": [
        [
          "every",
          18.1,
          18.39
        ],
        [
          "month",
          18.39,
          18.93
        ],
        [
          "the",
          18.96,
          19.07
        ],
        [
          "departmental",
          19.07,
          19.73
        ],
        [
          "manages",
          19.73,
          20.29
        ],
        [
          "meet",
          20.29,
          20.56
        ],
        [
          "to",
          20.56,
          20.66
        ],
        [
          "discuss",
          20.66,
          21.12
        ],
        [
          "high",
          21.12,
          21.33
        ],
        [
          "level",
          21.33,
          21.64
        ],
        [
          "issues",
          21.64,
          22.08
        ],
        [
          "in",
          22.08,
          22.18
        ],
        [
          "the",
          22.18,
          22.27
        ],
        [
          "company",
          22.27,
          22.75
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "final": true
},
```

This format repeats itself for each translated segment. I'm trying to extract all transcriptions, that is the value for `transcript`. I tried this:

```
index = 0

for [index]["transcript"] in ["results"][0]["alternatives"]:
    print (["results"][0]["alternatives"][index]["transcript"])
    index += 1
```

But this fails due to each transcription-object being embedded in a list. The full path for the first transcription value is:

```
d["results"][0]["alternatives"][0]["transcript"]
```

How can I iterate through this list to extract all transcription values and add them to a string variable?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for result in d['results']:
    for alternative in result['alternatives']:
        # add to your string here
        print alternative['transcript']
```

In general, python lets you iterate over objects in its lists instead of having to iterate using indices, which is more common in languages like C++.